# Any limit for asking question,Knowing about profile visitors

Tags: support, questions

How many no of question can we ask in stackoverflow ? Is there limit for that ? I am not talking about no of question per hour or minute but limit of total number question.And my second question is can we know about profile visitors ?

Comment: and please ask only one question per question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60508/how-can-i-figure-out-who-has-visited-my-profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many no of question can we ask in
>   stackoverflow ?

There is no limit to the number of questions you can ask on Stack Overflow.  You can ask as many as you want.  However, be sure that your questions are useful and belong on the site.  If your questions are flagged as spam or offensive your account could be suspended.

> can we know about profile visitors ?

Pretty much the only information you get about others visiting your profile is under your profile image on your profile page.  It will tell you how many people have viewed your profile.

Comment: There sort of is a limit - question asking is rate-limited, though I forget to what rate.

Comment: @Dominic, true there is a rate limit but the question specifically excludes rate limits.

Comment: @Dominic- What is rate limits means if reputation is lower we can't ask question,is like that ?

Comment: Which type of question can be flagged as spam or offensive ? –

Comment: @Harik, there is no set rule, other than any user with at least 15 rep can flag any question, answer or comment as spam or offensive.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37194/are-there-guidelines-on-what-to-flag-as-spam