# How can I figure out who has visited my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

How can I find out who are my profile visitors?

Comment: Install a virus on one of the Stack Exchange Valued Associate's work computers, log in very, very early one morning, and alter the codebase slightly.  If that's not an option, install a virus on every Stack Exchange user's computer and have it tell your web server every time they visit your profile. If that's not an option, work your way up the ranks in the NSA, then bug the dataline to the Stack Exchange servers. If that's not an option, buy Stack Exchange and Make It So(TM).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. This isn't Linkedin or some other glorified social network.

Comment: -1: A simple "you can't" would have been enough.

Comment: @Pekka: What's wrong with providing a rationale? I despise answers that don't.

Comment: you and I can't really provide a useful rationale, because we didn't build the site. Even though you are probably right, it adds no value to the answer and sounds unfriendly and snarky to me.

Comment: @Pekka: "It's not a social network" is also the standard answer of those who did build the site to questions about why SO isn't more like a social network. It's hardly a secret.

Comment: @Pekka: Conveying truth is not unfriendly or snarky.