# Who's viewed my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I figure out who has visited my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60508/how-can-i-figure-out-who-has-visited-my-profile)

Is there any way to see which users have viewed my profile?

Either a simple distinct list (each user would only appear once) or a complete history of who and when?

Comment: Why do you want this information? Could access to this data help the community at all?

Comment: I haven't (I think).

Comment: @Lix - curiosity, these could be users who have asked similar questions, share common interests or have favourited one of my questions - it could be a launching point for Chat.

Comment: @SteB That gets dangerously closed to social networking, any hint at which is often shot down here. ;)

Comment: While I don't want to turn SO into another social network site, doesn't any site with a vibrant community (like SO) have social-like attributes?

Comment: @SteB - No, we are all nerds here. We don't socialize.

Comment: Chat is really as far as the social aspect goes here. I also think that's part of its success. SO/SE does Q&A and does it really well. Keeping things "clean" of anything other than that is not a bad choice.

Comment: @Bart - good points, you've convinced me. After all, you can't see who up-voted or down-voted you.

Comment: Any attempt at starting a chat with "Hey @meagar, I noticed you just viewed my profile" would drive me away from this network forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: No. There is no way in which you can find out who viewed your profile. All this kind of data is anonymous. (If any of it is stored at all) I often wonder why the number of views is displayed at all.